# Reading undirected graph relationships (A-B) in R and renaming vertices with igraph

Tags: r, networking, routes, igraph

In R I'm trying to map all Madrid tube stations using **igraph** and then calculate the shortest route between two stations (just the number of stations, not the distance). I'm following this syntax: "An undirected graph with two vertices called ‘A’ and ‘B’ and one edge only:
    graph.formula(A-B)"

Below I just copy two tube lines for clarity's sake.

```
library("igraph")   
metro<- graph.formula(PinardeChamartin-Bambu-Chamartin-PlazadeCastilla-Valdeacederas-Tetuan-Estrecho-Alvarado-CuatroCaminos-RiosRosas-Iglesia-Bilbao-Tribunal-GranVia-Sol-TirsodeMolina-AntonMartin-Atocha-AtochaRenfe-MenendezPelayo-Pacifico-PuentedeVallecas-NuevaNumancia-Portazgo,LasRosas-AvenidadeGuadalajara-Alsacia-LaAlmudena-LaElipa-Ventas-ManuelBecerra-Goya-PrincipedeVergara-Retiro-BancodeEspana-Sevilla-Sol-Opera-SantoDomingo-Noviciado-SanBernardo-Quevedo-Canal-CuatroCaminos)  
sp <- get.shortest.paths(metro,from="Canal",to="Chamartin")  
V(metro)[sp[[1]]]
```

It seems to work but I have two question:
1. How can I input the tube stations (nodes) and their relationships A-B for long lists into the graph more efficiently, reading a csv for instance?

2.How can I rename those nodes to include tildes, spaces and "ñ"? Because I tried double quotes before and after each node's name but I get an error. A + sign. I haver checked the long string many times and I cannot see the error, no parenthesis missing.
Sorry if they're very basic questions. I'm a very novice user.
Thank you very much

Comment: There is comprehensive tutorial about using igraph in R here: http://igraph.wikidot.com/r-tutorial. It includes detailed section about reading ans storing the data, which is possible in several formats. Tilde above letters is a matter of encoding and should be handled when storing and loading the data.

Comment: The tutorial linked there is abandoned, and outdated, unfortunately. Might be still helpful, but you need to read the current documentation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, see `?graph.data.frame` and `?read.csv`.

I am not quite sure what you are asking in the second question, what is the error you are getting. Your code works fine for me, with the modification required for igraph 0.7.x:

```
V(metro)[sp$vpath[[1]]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "Canal"           "CuatroCaminos"   "Alvarado"        "Estrecho"       
# [5] "Tetuan"          "Valdeacederas"   "PlazadeCastilla" "Chamartin"
```

Comment: Sorry I meant that if instead of those names I use

Comment: Sorry I meant that if I use graph.formula("Pinar de Chamartin"-"Bambú"-"Chamartín"...etc) to include special characters I get an error when I enter the whole network. A string 5.000 characters long.A + symbol appears like when you leave an opening parenthesis. Can I rename those vertices to include those special characters? By the way, with my original code posted I get the error "invalid indexing of vertex seq" at home. I don't know why (a vertex zero?)

Comment: Please, forget the previous link. This one: pastebin.com/UAkQq5zQ

Comment: For the invalid indexing error message, please see the code in my answer. For the other issue, please put your data in a file. `graph.formula` is for creating small graphs. It does not work because the double quotes are not matching. But again, `graph.formula` is not for this size of data, put the data in a file. You probably already have it in a file.

Comment: You were spot on since the beginning. Your code posted for the invalid indexing. And I followed your own instructions to rearrange my data in a CSV and then used graph.data.frame igraph.sourceforge.net/igraphbook/igraphbook-creating.html It works fine. Brilliant!